# How do I know the length of a Weyl group element from its Weyl orbit result

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

How do I know the length of a Weyl group element from its Weyl orbit result?
For example, I know that $[2,2]$ under $s_1s_2s_1$ transforms into $[-2,-2]$,but given the result, how can I tell $l(s_1s_2s_1)=3$?

Comment: Are you sure this can be done? I mean, the action does not depend on a choice of simple reflections, does it?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Or can I tell if $l$ is even or odd?

Comment: I am not sure (I have never really thought about this in these terms).

Comment: If your vector $x$ happens to lie on a wall of a chamber (i.e. it has non-trivial stabilizer in the Weyl group), then given only $x$ and $\sigma(x)$ you cannot deduce $l(\sigma)$, because $\sigma$ and $\sigma s$ (where $s$ is the reflection w.r.t. the wall in question) have identical action on $x$ (and $s$ has an odd length). If $x$ is regular, then, as Tobias pointed out, the length will depend on the choice of basis. But parity will be well defined. The reason is that instead of the set of simple reflections you started with you will be working with their conjugates.

Comment: (cont'd) and conjugate elements of the Weyl group have the same parity. Look at the determinant of the underlying linear transformation.